# Node Devtools not connecting automatically

Tags: node.js, debugging, devtools

Normally, I would open **about://inspect** and click **Open dedicated DevTools for Node**, a new window pops up and would wait up to a node application is run with the **--inspect** flag, then it would attach automatically and I would debug my code. But it doesn't attach automatically anymore.

Anytime I make a change and want to debug, I have to relaunch the application, go to the **about://inspect** tab and click **inspect** again and close the older attached **DevTool** window.

Running Node v8.9.4 (also tested in Node v10.15.1) and Chrome 73 (MacOS).

To attach the debugger I run

```
node --inspect-brk -e "setInterval(() => console.log('working'), 1000)"
```

DevTools is configured to listen on the default port 9229. The problem persists even if I pass the port in **--inspect-brk=PORT** and configure **DevTools** to listen on **PORT**.